# PHP SOAP client accessing server on non-standard port

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

The service I'm trying to send requests to is accessible via a non-standard port - so not port 80. It is accessible locally via port 80. So I've tested the app locally and it works fine. But when I deploy it on the production server (not on the LAN), it fails.

Once again for clarity:

-dev server is on the LAN

-SOAP server is on the LAN

-production server is on the WAN

-SOAP server is accessible through the NAT/FW via a non-standard http port (not 80)

The soap client is created with the specified WSDL URI. For example:

```
$this->client = new Zend_Soap_Client('http://server.com:10080/path/service.asmx?WSDL');
```

But queries to not work:

```
$this->client->function($query);
```

I get an:

```
Internal Server Error
```

Exception thrown.

Is PHP broken in this regard? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround:

```
$this->client = new Zend_Soap_Client('http://server.com:10080/path/service.asmx?WSDL',array('proxy_host' => 'server.com', 'proxy_port' => 10080));
```

I pretend there is a proxy. I specify the proxy port as the server's port. This works. However, I'd still like to know if I'm making a mistake or if this is a bug in ZF or PHP. I filed a bug report with ZF for now:

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9626